# Stop Wonderlandads,com

Tags: popup

I have chrome installed on my windows 7. Whenever i click on any link on any site, the link opens as it should open normally but along with that, a new tab opens and a page open that new tab, which is advertisement page. The url of that page is wonderlandads dot com/afu.php?zoneid=437742 . Even when i click on scroll bar the same page opens in new tab.This is very irritating. I have tried to remove this adware by using Anti Malware Quickheal . I have also scanned my PC with antivirus. I do not have any unwanted software in my PC. I have tried reinstalling chrome and other browsers(IE, firefox) that i have. I am experiencing the same problem in firefox and IE. How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Task Scheduler (taskschd.msc).
Select Task Scheduler Library on the left panel.
On the upper center panel you will see a list of scheduled tasks.
On the lower center panel select Actions tab, it will show you which programs are launched by each task.
Go through the scheduled tasks one by one and find which of them open chrome.exe and load some URL. Delete those tasks.

The steps above are mentioned in the discussion here (https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/5rzpnn/need_help_removing_some_wonderlandads/) and this [article](http://www.okpckit.com/how-to-remove-wonderlandads-com-completely/). They seem to have helped many people had the same problem get rid of the wonderlandads.

It seems that this malware can be removed without using a security tool.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

Take the `admin rights` to modify the file

Then open with `Notepad`

Type `127.0.0.1 www.wonderlandads.com` in the last line and save

I hope this will save !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but after steps below the problem solved:

1. try chrome cleanup tool
2. try [malwarebytes](http://malwarebytes.com)
3. then install an adwclean tool
4. if the problem isn't solved yet, delete chrome and reinstall it

I hope you get rid of it.